# Display referenced content type on specific pages

Tags: 7, nodes, views

I have several basic **Pages**. I also have a content type of **Quick Link**. The Quick Links just have an image and a title. The site administrator should be able to specify **which pages have which Quick Links displayed on them**.

I thought this would be straightforward. I added a **Node Reference on Page** which points to Quick View as check boxes. I then created a (block) View which filtered for Quick Link content type. In the View I added a **Contextual Filter** for **Content: Quick Link**. I added the block to my region but nothing appeared on the front end :(.

I also tried the same but using a relationship in the View, and probably every other combination of configurations, but either nothing shows on any page or every Quick Link shows for every page.

I am new to Drupal so I apologise if I'm missing something really simple. I've searched around for the last two days but can't seem to find the same situation explained.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you see the content of your Page you see the node references?

Comment: Hi @moon.watcher, yes they do appear along with the other fields of the page node. I did set them as 'hidden' to being with, however in case these effected the relation I tried setting them as visible also. Neither effected the visibility of the block.

Comment: sorry, if you are seeing the node references, then is not clear to me your issue.